Why clicking at button at once the newly entered text is not passed into modal component?
On Laravel 11 / Livewire 3 site I have an input and button clicking on which modal is opened :
<div class="flex max-h-10 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="p-0 w-full  m-0">

        <input id="text" name="text" type="text"
               class="editor_form_input"
               maxlength="255"
               wire:model.live.change="noteText"
               autocomplete="off"
               placeholder="Fill string text "
        />
    </div>
    <div class="w-16 align-items-end justify-end align-top m-0 p-1">
        <button
            wire:click="$dispatch('openModal', { component: 'my-modal', arguments: {noteId: {{ $noteId }}, noteText: '{{ $noteText }}'} })">
              Open
        </button>

    </div>
</div>

$noteText - is public var defined in my component and opening modal I need to pass this var to modal.
It works OK if editing text I click out of input firstly (or click tab). But if I click at button at once, the newly entered text is not passed. How can I fix it ?
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
"wire-elements/modal": "^2.0"

